# iTunes Connect app submission - What notes should I give to the reviewer?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I'm submitting my first iOS app through iTunes Connect. What should I add under **App Review Information ->Notes** for the app reviewer?
Is it recommended to add some kind of tutorial/walkthrough to let the reviewer know what to do?

Comment: No. Don't call attention to yourself. If your app has no special features that _require_ instructions (e.g. how to log on to some sort of test server), just shut up and leave the Notes field blank.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When deploying our applications, we usually leave this field blank. You should definitely avoid entering tutorials and walkthroughs in the review notes.

***The application is getting approved for App Store. The question you have to ask yourself is: "If someone working for Apple, clearly with technical expertise, needs a specific tutorial, how can someone without any knowledge of development use my application?"***

*Those review notes are meant only for Apple Review Team, as previously mentioned, you should only add notes that are relevant for them, if some special registration is required for sandboxing the user (or you can provide login credentials in separate fields).*

Just make sure you are conforming to Apple's App Store rules and leave the field blank, unless it is absolutely necessary to tell something to reviewer. Do not use it to tell them, something is unfinished or beta, or such.

Comment: I agree with Legoless. This is a matter of experience dealing with app submissions. I would state that, for some apps, it's very convenient to put some notes. Let's say you create a compass app that is specially created for blind people. The app could get rejected right away if the reviewer doesn't know it adds a specific value to the user. BUT no walkthroughs or any similar thing.